# Find record with at least one HABTM related record in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models in my CakePHP application: `NewsArticle` and `Image`. A news article can have and belong to many images, but an image is not necessary.

How can I find the first news article in my application that has **at least one** associated image record, so as any news articles with no related image records are discarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use an INNER JOIN (see [Joins in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)) to limit the find() based on the existence of an associated HABTM item.

Answer (score 1):

Using join is quiet easy, just join the HABTM table using RIGHT JOIN, so only rows with HABTM records are gathered, this is my example for https://www.flylogs.com, i just wanted aircraft that was being used by at least on pilot and their names:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'contain' => array('Pilot.name'),
    'group' => 'Aircraft.id',
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'pilots_aircraft',
            'alias' => 'PilotAircraft',
            'type'  => 'right',
            'conditions' => 'Aircraft.id = PilotAircraft.aircraft_id'
        )
    ),
);

$aircraft = $this->paginate('Aircraft');
```

Important the group clausule, if not stated, it will gather a row for each pilot repeating aircraft!

Comment: Brilliant! Great for the code example too. Unfortunately I’ve already awarded the chosen answer, so the best I can do is offer you an up-vote.